# C++ STL set: Compare object with extrinsic state

Tags: c++, stl, compare, set

This definitions are inside of `OuterClass`:

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator ()(const T&, const T&);
};
typedef set<T, Compare> MySet;
```

My problem is that the compare function `operator ()` depends on the state of `OuterClass`. (`MySet` instances are used during an algorithm for an optimization and they have to sort differently at different stages.)

Is there any way/workaround to access nonstatic members of `OuterClass` from within the compare function `operator ()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way/workaround to access nonstatic members of OuterClass from within the compare function operator ()?

There is. Just write a user-defined constructor for `Compare` that accepts and stores a reference to `OuterClass`, this way:

```
struct Compare
{
    Compare(OuterClass& o) : oc(o) { }
    bool operator ()(const T&, const T&)
    {
        // Uses oc somehow...
    }
private:
    OuterClass& oc;
};
```

Then, when you create your set, you can do something like:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::set<T, Compare> MySet;

    OuterClass oc; // <== Construct an object of type Outerclass somehow...

    MySet ms(Compare(oc)); // <== Construct your comparator and pass it
                           //     in input to the constructor of std::set
}
```

Beware though: the ordering criterion should remain stable. Elements must always compare the same for the same set. Per paragraph 23.2.4/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation imposed by the comparison and not the
>   `operator==` on keys. That is, two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be equivalent if for the comparison
>   object `comp`, `comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) == false`. **For any two keys k1 and k2 in the
>   same container, calling `comp(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value**.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to look at the set constructors, so I did not recognize that I can create the comparator object by my own.  Thanks for the tip about the C++11 Standard -- I keep this in mind :)  Thanks a lot!